# Why checkbox boolean (Java, react) is showing always False, even if it should be True?

Tags: java, reactjs, checkbox, boolean

I have created a project with Java in backend, and React in frontend. But I have a variable that is boolean, for representation of this boolean value in frontend I use checkbox. If is checked it should be true, otherwise it should be false. In database is stored correctly.
But I create a table CRUD. In the table always is showing as false. Why ?

Here is the code:

```
const \[newPlanetIsDeleted, setNewPlanetIsDeleted\] = useState('');
```

For add:

```
api
            .post('http://localhost:8080/planet212257421/add', {
                name: newPlanetName,
                type: newPlanetType,
                isDeleted: newPlanetIsDeleted,
            })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                handleShowAllPlanet(); // Refresh the category list after successful addition
                setNewPlanetName(''); // Clear the input field
                setNewPlanetType('');
                setNewPlanetIsDeleted('');
                setSuccessMessage('Planet added successfully.');
                setTimeout(() => {
                    setSuccessMessage(null);
                }, 3000); // Hide success message after 3 seconds
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error);
            });
```

```
 <td>
                                        {editedData.id === planet.id ? (
                                            <input
                                                style={{ width: '180px', height: '50px' }}
                                                type="checkbox"
                                                checked={editedData.isDeleted}
                                                onChange={(e) => {
                                                    console.log('Checkbox value:', e.target.checked);
                                                    setEditedData({ ...editedData, isDeleted: Boolean(e.target.checked) });
                                                }}
                                            />
                                        ) : (
                                            planet.isDeleted? 'True' : 'False'
                                        )}
                                    </td>
```

```
<input
                                type="checkbox"
                                checked={newPlanetIsDeleted}
                                onChange={(e) => setNewPlanetIsDeleted(e.target.checked)}
                            />
```

```
POJO:
package com.inn.stadium.POJO;


import lombok.Data;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicInsert;
import org.hibernate.annotations.DynamicUpdate;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serial;


@NamedQuery(
        name = "Planet212257421.getAllPlanet",
        query = "select t from Planet212257421 t"
)

@Data
@Entity
@DynamicInsert
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "planet212257421")
public class Planet212257421 {

    @Serial
    public static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "isDeleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;
}
```

Why is showing always False. In some case I check and it should be True. I tried so many ways but doesn't work ?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer. Edit your question to add: 1) The exact payload you send to the backend 2) the pojo you deserialize into 3) if the deserialization is not broken, then saving into the database as well.